# Working directly from 'cloud' or 'online' github

Tags: python, github, cdn, portability

I don't precisely know how to frame this question for Google so I've come here.

I am currently doing a lot of python programming and am also using GitHub. However, my current situation has me moving around between different PCs quite often. I've started using WinPython to make my programming platform mobile.

Now I want to know if it is possible to work directly to and from a online GitHub repository without downloading or cloning the repo to my local drive?

I've seen some similar questions and have come across "CDN" and "jsDelivr". If CDNs are the way would someone mind explaining it to me simply?

Thank you all

Comment: CDNs definitely aren't the answer, but you might want to search for online IDEs. There are a whole bunch of them.

Comment: Hi Chris, I've tried repl.it but I am developing in a setting where the internet is not free but pay-as-you-go (per mb - barbaric I know) and this would require me to "download" all the necessary packages each and every time I use a new PC.

Comment: I don't think cloud IDEs _would_ require that (though I'm not familiar with repl.it). The whole point is that your development environment lives on the cloud. Keep looking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now I want to know if it is possible to work directly to and from a online GitHub repository without downloading or cloning the repo to my local drive?

Yes, since May 2020: [GitHub Codespaces now available in limited public beta](https://github.blog/changelog/2020-05-06-github-codespaces-now-available-in-limited-public-beta/)

> Now available in limited public beta, GitHub Codespaces allows for fully-featured dev environments directly inside of GitHub.
>
> With Codespaces, you have access to a containerized and customizable Visual Studio Code experience that can be configured to load your dotfiles, settings, and any extensions.

See [more at Codespaces](https://github.com/features/codespaces):

[image: https://github.githubassets.com/images/modules/site/workspaces/hero.av1.mp4]